# Promises & ES6 arrow functions immediately invoking another arrow function.

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a line of code that looks like this:

`promises = _.map(things, (thing) => () => moreThings(arg, arg2, arg3));`

Am I correct to say this is creating an array from each thing that is a function that calls moreThings? That it returns function call to moreThings() for each thing?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. "promises" will be an array containing elements returned by "things.length" times calls to "moreThings"

Comment: The result will be an array of functions. It will certainly not be an array of promises.

Comment: @11thdimension that's not correct. Look closely.

Comment: @torazaburo, it is correct, as he hasn't specified that he is expecting Promise as result, "say this is creating an array" and "it returns function call to moreThings"

Comment: `as he hasn't specified that he is expecting Promise as result` - the variable name suggests he does, and the first word in the question is `Promises`, so it's reasonable to point out that the result will have nought to do with promises

Comment: @11thdimension I think you're misreading the code. The function passed to `map` takes in `thing`, and returns `() => moreThings(arg, arg2, arg3))`. **That is a function**, obviously. `promises` will **not** be "an array of elements returned by ... calls to "moreThings: it will be an array of functions which **when invoked** call `moreThings`.

Comment: You're right, I misread it, it'll be a list of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I correct to say this is creating an array from each thing that is a function that calls `moreThings`?

Yes.

> That it returns function call to `moreThings()` for each thing?

Almost, but you can't really return a "function call". It returns a (list of) functions which makes a function call, whenever that function happens to be invoked.

What does any of this has to be with promises? And is it OK that you are ignoring the `thing` parameter to map?

Comment: This is from code I have to test which I'm trying to understand.

This const promises is used like this: `return async.parallel(promises).then((presumableResultFromPromises) => { more things in here });`

Comment: The variable name is confusing. They're not promises. They're functions, which is indeed what you would be passing to `async.parallel`).

Comment: but aren't there are promises branching off of async.parallel?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, and not that I can see from the source code (`async.parallel = function (tasks, callback) {
        _parallel(async.eachOf, tasks, callback);
    };`). You may be working with some patched/"enhanced" versions of async which converts callbacks into promises. That's common, but in this case mixing and matching the two models would seem to be a recipe for confusion.